# What are 'key business intelligence outputs' in the context of a public sector organization?

Tags: interviewing, presentations

I have applied for a Business Intelligence Developer job in a healthcare-related public sector organization and been asked to give a short verbal presentation on the following:

> Organization A has recently purchased a new clinical system called Clinical CMS. How would you go about developing the key business intelligence outputs from the system?

I have no idea what 'key business intelligence outputs' are in the context of this organization, what should I answer?

Comment: "Public sector job" is extremely wide-ranging. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you know much about business intelligence or statistics?

Comment: In a general sense, yes. I'm a programmer so I've dealt with a lot of databases. I just don't know how to answer this question very specifically.

Comment: Okay, why did I get voted down? At least let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really think it deserves down votes, but I'm not sure if this is on topic for The Workplace - the question you've been asked is very domain and job role specific, rather than about navigating the workplace in general. I'm not sure if there *is* a suitable SE site for it though. (Maybe programmers.se?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Business Intelligence, and not about navigating the workplace

Comment: I did consider that, but there is the whole interview/presentation aspect, and I think it is concerned more with what interviewers want to hear rather than actual business intelligence fundamentals. Considering that it does have relation to the field of interviewing I think it was unfair to get downvoted, but there you go..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not a great question  - you say "I have no idea what 'key business intelligence outputs' are `in the context of this organization`", and then you don't give us that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I'd start if I had this question:

1. Research Clinical CMS to see how is it generally used to prepare questions.
2. Interview the users of the system to determine how the system will be used and what metrics are going to be useful for reporting purposes among managers of those using the system.
3. Verify with technical staff that such reports can be built and provide a recommendation of how to build the reports.

The vagueness of the question is intentional as the key is what kind of high level plan would you give, what assumptions would you make and how long would it take are probably a few of the things they would be looking to see in this as it could well happen in the role as the developer may have to do the business analysis to produce future project plans.

Comment: I would add that if I were asking this question, I would be looking for someone who understood the meaning of the data not just techniques for manipulating it. You might also consider researching a bit into how HIPAA affects this and what security considerations you might have to have in reporting on this type of data.